# SoapUI set response data view

Tags: web-services, binary, soapui

I am in testing of a webservice, which gives response in binary format. So it is not human readable. Is it possible to make it readable without using script, so to set encoding in SoapUI?

Comment: Can you show the respective screen shot?

Comment: @Rio: There are only question marks, rectangles and percent signs in the output, so nothing informative.

Comment: What is character encoding you are using? You can check using `Menu -> Help -> System Properties` And what is the encoding supported by your application?

Comment: If you want to change the encoding, then you can look at my previous post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436512/how-to-handle-utf-8-character-encoding-in-http-log-in-soapui/44437807#44437807 and see if that helps.

Comment: @Rao: As I think it is not related to character encoding, because it is a different type of file.

Comment: May be you can show a screen shot of raw request / response.

Comment: It is RFC3161 based timestamping response.