# SoapUI doesn't print multi-byte characters correctly

Tags: java, soap, utf-8, character-encoding, soapui

I have a java web service that I want to invoke using soapUI.

I want that SOAPUI shows the character `’` correctly for example in a SOAP response I get the below response :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Internal server Error </faultstring>
         <detail>
            <MYENDPOINT_NAME xmlns="MY_XMLNS">
               <ns2:code>INTROUVABLE</ns2:code>
               <ns2:message>Le fichier n□a pas été trouvé</ns2:message>
            </MYENDPOINT_NAME>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want it to be like :

```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>500 Internal server Error </faultstring>
         <detail>
            <MY_ENDPOINT_NAME xmlns="MY_XMLNS">
               <ns2:code>INTROUVABLE</ns2:code>
               <ns2:message>Le fichier n’a pas été trouvé</ns2:message>
            </MY_ENDPOINT_NAME>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried to specify the charset in SOAP requests using `UTF-8` and in the launching script using

`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, but it still outputs the same result.

NB. the `500 Internal server Error` is a normal functional behaviour  in this case.

Comment: What does it show when you navigate thru Menu -> Help -> System Properties? Does it show the same encoding?

Comment: In fact it doesn't, I have these : `file.encoding=Cp1252` , `sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle`, `sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252`

Comment: Would you please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436512/how-to-handle-utf-8-character-encoding-in-http-log-in-soapui/44437807#44437807) to see if that helps ?

Comment: Thanks for helping :), in fact this is my [soapui.bat](https://codeshare.io/5OBA8W), I tried most of the known charsets

Comment: What version of soapui are you using? And you only want `Cp1252` as your char set?

Comment: I'm using `soapUI 4.5.0`, and of course I thought `UTF-8` is the charset I have to use, I found that in windows there are some other specifications

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161118/discussion-between-rao-and-o).

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things.

- Change the `file.encoding` value to `UTF-8` in the `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/soapui.bat`. Make sure you have a backup of the file before making any changes.
- In the SoapUI, Menu -> *`File -> Preferences -> UI Settings`*, Click the check box for *`Native L&F`*. Save the preferences. You many find more preferences [here](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/soapui-interface/preferences-and-settings.html) in the documentation.

Now close the SoapUI tool.

Open the command prompt; Go to `%SOAPUI_HOME%\bin` directory. Run `soapui.bat`

Suggestion: If you donot want to do that all the times, put `SOAPUI_HOME/bin` in PATH environment variable. Next time, `soapui.bat` should work from command prompt (irrespective of where you are present)

**EDIT:**

Another angle is to look at the application / server perspective. See if the application is configured to use `file.encoding` as `UTF-8`. If not, try configuring the application and retry.

Comment: It worked for me. However do think its a bug in SoapUI (default encoding for json is UTF-8?).  A simpler solution is to add this property to the SoapUI-5.y.z.vmoptions file in the bin folder. SoapUI by default in windows installs a shortcut which calls the exe iso the bat. Property can be verified by: Help -> SystemProperties.