# Extended ASCII characters getting converted to question mark

Tags: java, jboss, soapui, wireshark, extended-ascii

Whenever an extended ascii character (£, ß, etc) is passed from the body request of SOAP UI then the extended ascii character is getting converted to ?. We had tried this on the tool like **Wireshark** and **Netmon** and had found these extended ascii character is getting converted to ?.  The string which contains the extended ascii character password£ can be seen in hex format in both Wireshark and Netmon. The last character which is an extended ascii character £ is getting converted to ? (**password?**) and hence can see the hex value 3F (question mark).

We have tried Wireshark and Netmon on both Dev and ST environment. On Dev environment (Window OS) the extended ascii characters are getting converted to ? whereas on ST environment (Linux OS), we can see the correct extended ascii character.

Is there any need to make the change in JBoss so that it can accept these extended ascii character in right form?

Comment: It usually means you are using the wrong character set to convert bytes to characters. Without a [mcve] we can't help you further. Also, 'extended' ascii is a vague term that defines tens (if not hundreds) of character sets. Maybe you are trying to use ASCII (us-ascii) as character set, and that does not include those characters.

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436512/how-to-handle-utf-8-character-encoding-in-http-log-in-soapui/44437807#44437807 and update in you still have the issue.

Comment: Using the term "Extended ASCII" generally indicates you aren't using all the information you need to. What is the exact encoding? Once you know that, it's pretty much irrelevant if it has any similarity to another encoding.